# Why do I get a short circuit if I connect the red wire?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-circuits, electric-current, potential, short-circuits

Why the red wire generete a short-circuited with $I_2=0$ and $\Delta V_2=0$?

I have three loops and if I apply the 2nd Kirchhoff's rule, I will have

$$\sum_{\color{red}{\text{2nd loop}}} \Delta V=0$$

Why the current is not flows across $R_2$?

[image]

Comment: Hi everybody -- I have cleared out comments that were attempting to answer/provide hints on how to answer the question. If you have an answer that conforms to our policy on [answering homework-like questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/715/6634), then please post it as an answer. Comments should only be used for improving or clarifying the question. Thanks!

Comment: As a more on topic comment: what have you tried so far? What about Kirchoff's rules do you not understand that's preventing you from solving this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not understand the question. Is the question: "Why do I get a short circuit if I connect the red wire?"? The answer is you don't get a short circuit, instead the current will not flow through the resistor, R2. This is because Kirchoff's loop rule cannot be satisfied if any current flows through that path. Think about it, the voltage drop across R1 must be the voltage of the battery. Same goes for R3. But what about R2? It forms a loop that incorporates R1. If the voltage across R1 is the voltage of the battery, then there will be no voltage left anymore to drop! Because there is no voltage dropping across that resistor, there won't be any current. V=IR. If this doesn't help, I can draw a diagram, but yours is good enough if you think about that second loop.

Back to the original question. You could get a "short circuit" because you would be decreasing the equivalent resistance of the circuit from 2/3 R to R/2. This is from the equation of resistance in a parallel. The decreased resistance implies an increased current if you keep the voltage the same.

Comment: @Sebastiano I have edited my answer to address your main question. To get the resistances mentioned in my answer, you could use the equivalent resistance in parallel law.